# Can't authenticate correctly with headers (HttpClient)

Tags: c#, json, authentication, xamarin

I've checking many forums but I can't make it work. I'm trying to authenticate with headers to an url that will return a `JSON` string if authentication were successful. In `Postman` I simply used `Get` method with `username` and `password` in header to get the `JSON` data. What changes do I need to make my following C# code achieve same thing? I think I even failed to add username and `password` into `headers`.

```
  public async Task<string> LogMeIn(string username, string password)
        {
            var client = new HttpClient {
                BaseAddress = new Uri("http://x.com")
            };

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] {

                new KeyValuePair<string,string>("grant_type","password"),
                       new KeyValuePair<string,string>("Username ", username),
                       new KeyValuePair<string,string>("Password", password)
                    });

            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

            var response = await client.PostAsync("/login", content); //should it be GetAsync?


            var jsonResp = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            var jsonResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonResult>(jsonResp); //JsonResult = class for json

            return jsonResult.token;
       }
    }
```

Comment: Show the raw request that worked when done in Postman. You explanation is not very clear. maybe the raw request will shed some light on what you are asking

Comment: The default postman request uses GET and not POST

Comment: I get like `{"Something": {
      "aBool": 0,
      "aString": "abc"
    },
    "Another": {
      "aBool": 0,
      "aString": "abc"
    }, "token" : "xxx"}}`

Comment: @Cheesebaron I know that, but how do I correct my code?

Comment: @user7399041, You need use GetAsync for Method type GET: await client.GetAsync("/login", content).ConfigureAwait(false);

Comment: @user7399041 you are showing the response not the request. I am trying to determine is the content in your example belong in the header.

Comment: @Nkosi Not sure how to get raw request I made. Inside header tab, I added "`Content-Type`" as key = "`application/json`" as value. **&** "`Username`" as key, "`theUserValue`" as value **&** "`Password`" as key, and "`UserPassword`" as value. I used `GET`.

Comment: @JuniorPorfirio I can't have `content` in `GetAsync`. I get the error: "`cannot convert from 'System.Net.Http.FormUrlEncodedContent' to 'System.Threading.CancellationToken`"

Comment: @user7399041 The question is not clear. without a [mcve] there is not much the community can do to help.